# VBA function to define an array and find its maximum value

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write code to run some calculations on a range of numbers. The range is defined from 1 to a cell value picked from a cell. And then finally find the maximum value from all the outputs of that calculation.

1. A for loop that runs from x=1 to a value taken from one cell
2. Some if conditions that are used based on the value of x, to find y.
3. Y is then stored into an array arr (of length same as the no of the times the loop runs) at the end of each iteration.
4. Maximum value of array arr is taken and stored in another cell. Which is the final output.

This is my attempt at the code.

```
Sub Max_deflection()

Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate

Dim x As Integer
y As Single
Dim L As Single
Dim a As Single, b As Single, c As Single, d As Single, p1 As Single, p2 As Single, p3 As Single, p4 As Single, flex As Single, m As Single


L = Range("B9").Value
a = Range("E3").Value
b = Range("E4").Value
c = Range("E6").Value
d = Range("E8").Value
p1 = Range("D3").Value
p2 = Range("D4").Value
p3 = Range("D5").Value
p4 = Range("D6").Value
flex = Range("B17")

Dim arr(L + 1)



For x = 1 To RoundDown(L, 0)

    If x > 0 And x < a Then
        y = (p1 * x * (L - a) 
    ElseIf x > a And x < b Then
        y = (p2 * x * (L - b)
    ElseIf x > b And x < c Then
        y = (p3 * x * (L - c)) 
    ElseIf x > c And x < d Then
        y = (L - d) ^ 2)) / (6 * L * flex)
    Else
        y = (2 * L - d) / (6 * L * flex)
    End If
    
    arr(x) = y
    Next x
    
m = max(arr)
Range("A29").Value = m


End Sub
```

Not sure if I've used the sub command and activate command the right away. I just tried to mimic the examples I saw online.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't share screenshots of code as it is impossible to reproduce. Instead, put your code in code blocks (see [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).

Comment: Thank you for the headsup. I was posting the comment from my mobile hence the screenshot. But I managed to edit the code into the answer now.

Comment: Now, which is the question? What's wrong with your code? What does "my broken attempt" mean? Should we deduce looking at it? Does it return an error? If yes, what error on which line? If not, what does it do instead of what you need?

Comment: Well I don't get any results at all. There don't seem to be any error messages if that's what you mean. 
If what I did was right, I should get the output in the A29 cell, right?

Comment: Try rewriting the example, using [MCVE]. For example, instead of `L = Range("B9").Value`, write `L = 42`, thus it will be way easier for someone to copy and paste the code and replicate it. The formula `y = (p1 * x * (L - a) * (L ^ 2 - x ^ 2 - (L - a) ^ 2)) / (6 * L * flex) + (p2 * x * (L - b) * (L ^ 2 - x ^ 2 - (L - b) ^ 2)) / (6 * L * flex) + (p3 * x * (L - c) * (L ^ 2 - x ^ 2 - (L - c) ^ 2)) / (6 * L * flex) + (p4 * x * (L - d) * (L ^ 2 - x ^ 2 - (L - d) ^ 2)) / (6 * L * flex)` is not needed for the example, write `y = L*2` to simplify it and bring it to the core of the problem.

Comment: But i have to know if the way I've written is right or not. I understand your requirement for it. But I'm completely new to this so I can't be sure if anything I've written is right. The only thing the code serves as is a picture of my intent. But I will make the edits on the formulae.

Comment: `Dim arr(L + 1)`   needs to be `dim arr()` then `redim arr(L+1)`

Comment: Please, try running the code line by line and see if your conditions are met and the code add elements to the array. Moving the mouse cursor over a variable (`y`) will show you the variable value. Also, try `m = Application.max(arr)`. I cannot understand how your code does not return any error... Being in VBE press 'Tools' -> 'Options' -> 'General' and see what radio button is `True` in 'Error Trapping' frame.

Comment: @FaneDuru you're right it does return error and highlights the first line 
Error says "statement invalid outside type block"

Comment: This mean that you did not put all the code lines inside the Sub. Something like `Sub YourSub`, the code follows and ends with `End Sub`. Do you have some code line outside `Sub Max_deflection()` - `End Sub`? Which is this "first line"? Does it appear in the code you show us?

Comment: @FaneDuru You're right, thanks. The definition of variable y, was wrong. That's fixed now.
The error I get now highlights the RoundDown fucntion and the sub. Error says "Sub or Function not defined"

Comment: Try `Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown` instead.

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.RoundDown`

Comment: @VictorColomb Thanks! The error has moved onto the max function now. "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". Should I try Application.WorksheetFunction.max instead?

Comment: yes, but `Application.Max`, as I recommended above, also works

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks! I am getting outputs now at least! Now I just need to check if the process is right. From what you can see, does my code follow the methodology I mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yes, it does, but "Some if conditions" can be evaluated only by you, doing as I (also) recommended above (F8 and run the code line by line)...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks a lot for your patience. I had to make heavy edits to everything I posted but I'm getting the hang of this forum. Really grateful.